# Connected subgroup of $(K^\times)^n$ of Zariski dimension 1

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Is the following true even if $K$ is not algebraically closed ? If so, I am looking for a proof of it.

> > **Claim.** Let $K$ be a field of characteristic $0$. A connected subgroup of $(K^*,\times)^n$ defined by polynomial equations and having Zariski dimension 1 is isomorphic to $K^\times$.